# Python Random Forest Prediction Probabilities Reliability

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction, reliability

TLDR: RF prediction probabilities are not consistent

I have created a calibrated Random Forest Model to predict probabilities for attrition of the workforce, but what I am finding is that probabilities for the same employee changes drastically over the span of a day. So for example, lets say I developed the model yesterday, and employee A has a prediction probability of .007560, I run the same employee today through the model, and it outputs the probability is .684939. The only difference between yesterday's data and today's data for this employee will be things like tenure, which is a minimal difference (i.e., tenure has increased by 1 day or .003 years). So reliability in the model predicting probabilities is not there.

I know what is causing this difference: the slight changes in these tenure variables but I don't know why. I suspect over-fitting? But I followed CV procedures when developing the model (code is below) and accuracy didn't really change between train and test sets.

What makes it more confusing is that if I create a new model today, and predict probabilities on this employee's data from yesterday and today, the results are consistent for both days at 0.007764, which is close to the original .007560. I presume its not exactly the same because there is a slight change in the data for the employee. So why the model can provide consistent probabilities on "past" data, but not on "future" data is beyond me.

I am only giving one example here, but this is happening on a larger scale, hence why it is an issue. So my solution for right now is to develop the model every time I need to update workforce attrition probabilities, but keeping all of the parameters the same. I don't like this approach because for the ML pipeline, id refer to just load the saved model and run the data through it, rather than developing the model and run the data through it. Also, would like to understand what is happening here. Below is my code, the example given here is a calibrated RF model, but same thing is happening with a non-calibrated RF model as well. Thanks!

```
#train model    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_final, y_vars, test_size=0.5, random_state=20)
#CALIBRATED
rf_unfit1=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1800, max_features='auto', max_depth=100, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, bootstrap=False)
rf_cv=CalibratedClassifierCV(rf_unfit1,method='sigmoid',cv=3)
rf_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
filename=r'C:\Users\Downloads\model'
joblib.dump(rf_cv, filename)
#make predictions
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\test.csv')
rf_cv = joblib.load(open(r'C:\Users\Downloads\model', 'rb'))
final_cv_probs=rf_cv.predict_proba(df)[:,1]
print(final_cv_probs)
```

Below are the prediction probabilities for the same employee. Input variables are Columns A - G. Highlighted columns show input variables with slight changes in variable values as days progress.
[image]

Comment: Over-fitting is unrelated to load/save issues for your network. Your TLDR indicates that this is happening when the saved model is reloaded, but nothing in your description indicates a situation where you are saving and reloading the model. 

What makes you think your issue has anything to do with saving/loading?

Comment: Ive updated the TLDR, I dont think this has anything to do with save/reload